# How to setup passenger with hapijs v18*?

Tags: passenger, hapi.js

I am trying to run a basic hapi v18 setup on a Digital Ocean droplet with phussion passenger and nginx.

I have made several searches on google on how to setup hapi with passenger but all info I found is on old hapi versions (previous v17).

This is all the code I have for my test:

```
'use strict';

if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    PhusionPassenger.configure({ autoInstall: false });
}

const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');

const init = async () => {

    if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
        // Requires Passenger >= 4.0.52!
        server = new Hapi.Server('/passenger');
    } else {
        server = new Hapi.Server('localhost', 3000);
    }

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path:'/',
        handler: (request, h) => {

            return 'Hello World!';
        }
    });

    await server.start();
    console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {

    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

When checking nginx error log, I get the following:

```
App 21225 output: TypeError: Cannot create property 'routes' on string '/passenger'
App 21225 output:     at Object.internals.setup (/var/www/hapi-18-test/code/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/core.js:598:21)
App 21225 output:     at new module.exports.internals.Core (/var/www/hapi-18-test/code/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/core.js:54:46)
App 21225 output:     at new module.exports (/var/www/hapi-18-test/code/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/server.js:22:18)
App 21225 output:     at init (/var/www/hapi-18-test/code/index.js:13:18)
App 21225 output:     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/hapi-18-test/code/index.js:37:1)
App 21225 output:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
App 21225 output:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
App 21225 output:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
App 21225 output:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
App 21225 output:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
```

I just followed the example on passenger's website but I guess it is not working because of hapi's new versions.

So, how can I run hapi v18 on passenger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution by reading the Hapi documentation.

We have to replace:

```
if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
        // Requires Passenger >= 4.0.52!
        server = new Hapi.Server('/passenger');
    } else {
        server = new Hapi.Server('localhost', 3000);
    }
}
```

With:

```
if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
        // Requires Passenger >= 4.0.52!
        server = new Hapi.Server({ port: '/passenger' });
    } else {
        server = new Hapi.Server('localhost', 3000);
    }
}
```